# Express: session secret

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

my question is about Express session. in express-session config we declare property named secret like this

```
   app.use(session({
   secret: 'stringForHash',
   resave: false, //optional
   saveUninitialized: true //optional
}));
```

and i want to know what if someone knows that secret keyword, is that vulnerability? what person (for example attacker) can do with that?

Comment: Interesting reading [here](https://martinfowler.com/articles/session-secret.html)

Comment: nice article, thanks